# Using scala.sys.process to invoke echo on Windows 7

Tags: shell, scala, windows-7, cross-platform, dos

I am trying to use an external program from within Scala that accepts its input from the standard input stream.

Code roughly the equivalent to the following runs on Linux but raises an exception when run on Windows (tested on Windows 7). The exception's description states that the echo command cannot be found.

```Scala
def invokeProgram(data : String) {
       import scala.sys.process._
       val cmdEcho = Seq("echo", data)
       val cmdProgram = Seq("program")
       println((cmdEcho #| cmdProgram).!!)
}
```

The code works correctly on Linux but fails as described on Windows, yet the echo command is common to both platforms and its usage is syntactically the same for my purposes. Is this as simple as echo not being in PATH? Is there even a separate echo.exe on Windows or is it bundled into something else? The invoked program can be made to accept its input from a temporary file which is what I will fall back to if I cannot resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `echo` at all. Instead, use the #< method of [ProcessBuilder](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilder). Here is an example:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream
import scala.sys.process._

val data = "hello"
val is = new ByteArrayInputStream(data.getBytes)
"cat" #< is ! //complicated way to print hello
```

Comment: Thank you this solved my problem, edited example to remove cat reference as the whole idea was for Linux/Windows cross platform development.

Answer (score 4):

The difference is this:

```
dcs@shadowfax:~$ which echo
/bin/echo
```

That is, on Unix the `echo` command is actually a binary, though most shells implement it as a builtin. On Windows, on the other hand, there's no binary called `echo.exe` (or `echo.com`, etc). It's solely a builtin command of the shell.

Comment: That was one of my theories as to the cause, thank you for confirming that. I'm not sure that 'which' proves by itself that echo is a separate executable as it could still be bundled into a single monolithic shell executable with different hard or symbolic links to it for each command. I'm sure I've used a system in which this was the case though it doesn't seem in line with the Unix philosophy.

Comment: @DuncanACoulter It proves that there's a binary by the name `echo` in the PATH. When you call `"echo x".!`, it searches for a binary by the name `echo` in the PATH, therefore, the former proves the latter will work.

Comment: Sorry I think I'm drifting far off topic and not explaining myself terribly well. I was just thinking of a scenario where each command line utility e.g. /bin/echo or /bin/ls was actually a symbolic link to a single executable say /bin/shell which behaved differently based on the name of the symbolic link it was called through (say by examining argv[0] in C++). In that case executing "which echo" would return /bin/echo even though there was no such binary. The alternative is that I did explain myself clearly but it wasn't a terribly good point after all. Either way thank you.

Comment: @DuncanACoulter Yes, I understood that, but that is irrelevant. The important thing is that executing `/bin/echo ok` echoes "ok" -- it doesn't matter whether `echo` is a link to a shell or not, as long as it does what it is supposed to do.